# Restrict overlays in mapbox

Tags: javascript, dictionary, overlay, leaflet, mapbox

So I am creating a map using Leaflet and Mapbox with multiple overlays and base maps. Currently I have a layers control where these are separated and you can only show one base map at a time, but all the overlays can be shown at once.

However, I have two overlays which interfere with each other and I would like to make it so that if one is checked in the control, the other is unchecked and vice versa. Is there any way to do this?

I am anticipating something like this, but am open to any suggestions.

```
var layer1 = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapid1');
var layer2 = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapid2');

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, {"L1": layer1, "L2": layer2}).addTo(map);

map.on("overlayadd", function(e) {
  if (e.name === "L1"){
    L.layers.control.uncheck(layer2);
  } else if (e.name === "L2") {
    L.layers.control.uncheck(layer1);
  };
});
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/tyojp7dp/).

I don't know if there's an easier way. It seems the library doesn't offer many options to manipulate the `L.control.layers` overlays.

What I'm doing is firing a click on the conflicting overlay. To achieve this, a little DOM manipulating is needed. You can store an id reference when creating overlay's label.